# Python, writing two codes within one code

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, merge, block

**Input:**

```
ID   information1
Aa   information1-1
CC   information1-2
Ca   Homo sapiens
Da   information1-4
//
ID   information2
Aa   information2-1
CC   information2-2
Ca   information2-3
Da   information2-4
//
```

**Expected output:**

```
ID   information1
Aa   information1-1
Ca   Homo sapiens
Da   information1-4
//
```

**Code1:**

```
# Step1
with open(input_file, 'r') as input, open('temp.txt', 'w') as temp:

    for line in input: 

        if not line.startswith('CC   '):
            temp.write(line)
```

**Code2:**

```
# Step2
word = 'Homo sapiens'
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as input, open(output_file, 'w') as output:

    for block in input.read().split('//'):

        if word in block:
        
            output.write(block)
            output.write('//')
```

I want to proceed with two steps within one code, not two separate codes. Is there any suggestion for me?!

Comment: What do you mean by "two codes/steps within one code"? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: *"the codes work well enough each other"* -- How's that? `output_from_Step1` is not defined, and `input` is a file object so it's not callable.

Comment: Ok, cool. So you want to filter by line and filter by block. Have you already tried anything to combine them? Is it possible `line.startswith('CC   ') and word in line`?

Comment: 1) I mean, have you already tried anything to combine the two steps? To me it looks pretty straightforward, so I'm not sure what problem you're facing. 2) That doesn't answer my question. Let me rephrase, if it helps: is it possible that a line starts with `'CC   '` **and** contains `word`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one pass by building a "block" of potential output lines as you read the input line by line. Consider this:

```
word = 'Homo sapiens'
infile = 'blockin.txt'
outfile = 'blockout.txt'

with open(infile) as txtin, open(outfile, 'w') as txtout:
    block = []
    useblock = False
    for line in txtin:
        if line.startswith('//'):
            if useblock:
                block.append(line)
                txtout.write(''.join(block))
                useblock = False
            block = []
        elif not line.startswith('CC   '):
            block.append(line)
            if not useblock and word in line:
                useblock = True
```